# Problem with allocating a large dynamic 3d array

Tags: c++

Hi I am learning how to allocate and delete a dynamic 3d array. The code below runs fine with `int size{100}` but if I increase the array size to, say `int size{900}` visual basic throws an exception of bad memory allocation and point to this line: `array3d[y][z] = new int[size];`. Why is this happening?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int size{ 100 };
    // Defined 3D array on the first pointer to pointer to pointer to int (X-axis)
    int*** array3d{ new int** [size] };

    for (int y{ 0 }; y < size; ++y) {
        // Second pointer to pointer to int (Y-axis)
        array3d[y] = new int* [size];

        for (int z{ 0 }; z < size; ++z) {
            // Third pointer to int (Z-axis)
            array3d[y][z] = new int[size];

        }
    }

    // Delete array3d[][Y][Z]
    for (int y{ 0 }; y < size; ++y) {
        for (int z{ 0 }; z < size; ++z) {
            delete[] array3d[y][z];
        }
        delete[] array3d[y];

    }

   // Delete array3d's last X-axis
   delete[] array3d;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are building a 32 bit application. In 32 bit mode on windows you may be limited to less than 2 GB of address space by default. Related: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/largeaddressaware-handle-large-addresses?view=msvc-170](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/largeaddressaware-handle-large-addresses?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Yes currently at x86 config, trying x64... I get it now int pointers are 8 bytes... So  900*900*900*8 = 5.8Gb

Comment: If you enter data into the pointer address will it go above 5.8Gb?

Comment: In x64 on windows the pointers are 64 bit. Integers are still 32 bit. There is no limitation for accessing 5.8GB

Comment: I mean pointer essentially stores the address that it is pointing to. So that means you will need memory to store the address (5.8gb). On top of that for the actual data itself `int` (4 bytes) do you need additional memory? (900*900*900*4 = 2.9gb)? 

So in total there are 5.8gb + 2.9gb = 8.7gb worth of ram used? Thanks

Comment: To save memory, allocate a simple one-dimensional array: `int* arr = new int[size*size*size];`. To access an element at `(x, y, z)`, write `arr[x*size*size + y*size + z]`. Wrap that in a class, for convenience. This way there's no overhead for storing pointers. Though for 900x900x900 array, you'd still need an 64-bit build; there are more than 2GB worth of ints alone.

Comment: Your current scheme requires `size*(size+1)` pointers, not `size^3`. For `size==900` and 8-byte pointer, that's only ~6MB overhead, not 5GB

Comment: Thank you Igor! Ah yes there are two levels of pointer only so `2*size` but where is `+1` comes from?

Comment: `int*** array3d{ new int** [size] };` allocates `size` pointers, the loop right after allocates `size*size` more.

Comment: Got it i understand now